# C# httpwebrequest get 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

```
try
{
     HttpWebRequest request = (Http WebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://yigg.de/login");
     request.Method = "GET";
     request.Timeout = 10000;
     request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
     request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
     request.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
     request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) (Prevx 3.0.5)";
     CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
     cc.Add(new Uri("http://yigg.de/login"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user", "pass"));
     request.Credentials = cc;
     request.CookieContainer = container;
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
     string htmldoc = reader.ReadToEnd();
     response.Close();
     return htmldoc;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     return ex.Message;
}
```

I used above code and i always get "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized". Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: is `user/pass` authorized to access that site?

Comment: maryreiter938:cfhj48ZUIJ. I use get method but receive 401 Unauthorized so i use creadentials for request